# Are Stored Procedures DDL or DML?

Tags: stored-procedures, ddl, dml

Where DDL and DML are basically:

> - DDL =  Data Definition Language
> - DML =  Data Manipulation Language

I have always classified Stored Procedures as DDL since they uses [Structured Query language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language#Structured_query_language).

But recently I was debated that Stored Procedures should be DML or should belong to a different classification since they internally have DDL and DML.

I searched in Internet and I didn't find any trustful documentation where Stored Procedures are classified as DDL, then I couldn't argue more...

Therefore, the question is simple: **Are Stored Procedures DDL? or DML?**

**Edited**
This question has been marked as deleted, which I am partially agree, but the issue is that other questions just explains what is DDL vs DML, but there is any documentation that classify where *Stored Procedures* should be classified.

Comment: A stored procedure is *created* using DDL, but can _contain_ DML and DDL

Comment: Agree with you, but do you have any link or documentation that indicates that?

Comment: All manuals for all DBMS

Comment: Thanks but by chance could you please point me to one of this manuals... I know it is a matter of common sense, but I need to provide proofs, documentation, manuals, or something... and I google it and didn't find anything were explicitly say stored procedures are DDL